# Problem with calling method with getters and setters

Tags: java, getter-setter

Im working on small project and i need a little help. 
So, i have class with getters and setters and to string method at the and. Also i have one method to calculate something, so, can i call that method in my input?

```
 User user1 = new User(2, 14, method, "Mark", "John", "055-555-633");
```

So as you can see in my code, where i type "method" i would like to call real method. And my method look like this(is that problem?):

```
public void amount(Gamehouse g){
    int amount = i.pricePerHour() * getHowMuchUserWantHours();
}
```

So yes, i need to make program print automatic amount in my user1 user. Instead of where I put "method" can i put my methot "amount" and make it calculate amount of price for me automatic? Beucase this "2" in my user1 User is how much user want hours, so 2*50 for example.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html

Comment: So i dont need new method, just to put my method under getAmount?

Comment: `public int amount(Gamehose g) {

 return amount * g.getPricePerHours();
 `

Comment: post complete code that helps to get better help. Right now it is not very clear what is required

Comment: I use two class's for this and it's not on English, i would but idk is that even usefull

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 'i' is a Class variable, you would define the method as:

```
public double amount(Gamehouse g){
    return i.pricePerHour() * getHowMuchUserWantHours();
}
```

And call it as:

```
User user1 = new User(2, 14, amount(), "Mark", "John", "055-555-633");
```

Comment: "Cannot find symbol: amount" ...

Im calling this user1 in my main class, and this method is in my class User so, and im using "pricePerHour" from another class, which is "gamehouse"

Comment: If the amount method is defined within the User class, you can probably remove this argument from the User constructor and just have the constructor call hit method internally to set the value.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate it in the constructor instead if you are already sending 2 (`getHowMuchUserWantHours`) to the constructor.

```
public User(int hours, int unknown, int pricePerHour, String surname, String first name, String phone) {
    this.amount = hours * pricePerHour;
    // rest of fields
}
```

Create user

```
User user = new User(2, 14, g.getPricePerHours(),  "Mark", "John", "055-555-633");
```

this makes sense if also hours is a member of User, if not and it is only used for calculation then skip it as parameter

```
public User(int unknown, int amount, String surname, String first name, String phone) {
    this.amount = amount;
    // rest of fields
}
```

add calcAmount method to User class

```
public static int calcAmount(int hour, int pricePerHour) {
    return hour * pricePerHour;
}
```

and create user

```
User user = new User(14, calcAmount(2, 2* g.getPricePerHours()),  "Mark", "John", "055-555-633");
```